# How can I export image from every row of a dataTable to pdf using PrimeFaces DataExporter?

Tags: primefaces, preprocessor

I have a XHTML displaying rows from a dataTable having few texts columns and one image column. I have been able to export the text columns for all the records in pdf, but I am not able to export the images in the rows. I searched in lots of posts to find out a way **to export the images from the rows**, but failed. Please note that **I am not looking for exporting a single image** for header or footer, which can be handled by preProcessor attribute in the p:dataExporter tag. I found good hints/examples for exporting single image using PreProcessor in dataExport tag. The hints are working fine for me. But I was unable to find any hint/example for row-wise image export. Please help!

**My technology stack:**
JSF2, PrimeFaces 4.0, itext-1.1.4, JDK1.8, GlassFish Server 4

**My current xhtml output** given below. I need to export the green ticks and red crosses to pdf.

[My current xhtml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp1sG.png)

**My JSF/XHTML code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/templates/common.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:panelGroup id="formTitle" layout="block">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle}"></h:outputText>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
                <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bundle.ListUsersEmpty}" rendered="#{usersController.items.rowCount == 0}"/>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{usersController.items.rowCount > 0}">
                    <p:dataTable id="dtUsers" value="#{usersController.items}" var="item" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500">
                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.id}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_id}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                           <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" /> 
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.userName}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_userName}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                           <h:outputText value="#{item.userName}" /> 
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.userPassword}" exportable="false">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_userPassword}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.userPassword}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="userActiveCol" sortBy="#{item.userActive}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_userActive}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:graphicImage id="yesId" value="/img/Yes.png" alt="Yes" rendered="#{item.userActive == 'Y'}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage id="noId" value="/img/No.png" alt="No" rendered="#{item.userActive == 'N'}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.userSource}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_userSource}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{(item.userSource == 'ORGANIZATION')?'Organization':
                                                   (item.userSource == 'VENDOR')?'Vendor':
                                                   (item.userSource == 'VENDORRESOURCE')?'Vendor Resource':
                                                   (item.userSource == 'CUSTOMER')?'Customer':'Not Known'}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.resourceId}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_resourceId}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.resourceId}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsersTitle_resourceName}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{usersController.getResourceName(item)}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="&nbsp;" exportable="false">
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="formRowAction">
                                <p:commandLink action="#{usersController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListUsersViewLink}"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="formRowAction">
                                <p:commandLink action="#{usersController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListUsersEditLink}"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="formRowAction">
                                <p:commandLink action="#{usersController.destroy}" 
                                               value="#{bundle.ListUsersDestroyLink}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="formBottomActions">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{usersController.prepareCreate}" value="#{bundle.ListUsersCreateLink}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandLink value="#{bundle.ExportPDF}" immediate="true" id="generatePDFId" ajax="false">
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="dtUsers" fileName="Users"/>
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:link outcome="/subMenu" value="#{bundle.SubMenuLink}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{menuHandler.returnToMainMenu}" value="#{bundle.mainMenuLink}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

**PDF that is currently getting generated**. The green ticks and red crosses should appear in the column "User Active".

[PDF that is currently getting generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDjiR.png)

Comment: were you successful? If so, post it to us :D

Answer (score 1):

The PrimeFaces exporter does not export images from cells only text.  You will have to write a custom PDF exporter to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that PrimeFaces does not export images from cells. Do you have any link (to post) or example of writing a customer PDF exporter for exporting images from cells?

Comment: I do not. Sorry!